# How can I target a module?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I was searching a bit through the reference assemblies and noticed a weird comment/snippet:

```
// Attribute class used by the compiler to mark modules.
// If present, then debugging information for everything in the 
// assembly was generated by the compiler, and will be preserved
// by the Runtime so that the debugger can provide full functionality
// in the case of JIT attach. If not present, then the compiler may
// or may not have included debugging information, and the Runtime 
// won't preserve the debugging info, which will make debugging after
// a JIT attach difficult. 
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly|AttributeTargets.Module, AllowMultiple = false)] 
[ComVisible(true)]
public sealed class DebuggableAttribute : Attribute 
{
```

Now I hopped onto the `AttributeTargets` and was wondering what a Module is in C#/.NET.

```
  [Flags]
  [ComVisible(true)]
  [__DynamicallyInvokable]
  [Serializable]
  public enum AttributeTargets
  {
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] Assembly = 1,
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] Module = 2,
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] Class = 4,
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] Struct = 8,
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] Enum = 16,
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] Constructor = 32,
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] Method = 64,
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] Property = 128,
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] Field = 256,
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] Event = 512,
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] Interface = 1024,
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] Parameter = 2048,
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] Delegate = 4096,
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] ReturnValue = 8192,
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] GenericParameter = 16384,
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] All = GenericParameter | ReturnValue | Delegate | Parameter | Interface | Event | Field | Property | Method | Constructor | Enum | Struct | Class | Module | Assembly,
  }
```

So my question is - how can I target a module from C# code with an attribute?

Comment: That attribute is already emitted by the compiler.  Never write it yourself, getting it wrong has *very* detrimental side-effects.

Comment: @HansPassant alright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `module` qualifier, e.g.:

```
[module: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default)]
```

Can be placed in any .cs file above any namespace/class declaration.

A module is a container for types. Most compilers (including C#) emit a single module per assembly. You can view module-level attributes in disassembler tools such as ILSpy.

Note that this is not the same as a VB.NET module, which is similar to a C# static class.

Comment: And where would I place it? Above a class, above a namespace?

Comment: AssemblyInfo.cs is the best place for it. It cannot be inside a block or after anything other than the using statements, or after other assembly/module-level attributes.